# How to gon image when content not have image and show image it when have

Tags: android, android-studio

i want to gon imageView when content haven't image and show it if content have image,i put images in drawable folder and use database field for add image names and if content haven't image i write in the field "not" instead of image name. i wrote this code:

```
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.show_img);
         if(content.getImg() == "not") {
                    img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else {
                    String image = content.getImg();
                    int imageResource = c.getResources().getIdentifier(image, "drawable",
 c.getPackageName());
  img.setImageResource(imageResource);
  Log.i(DBAdapter.TAG, image);
                }
```

in log message shows image name but in application display default src image and don't show images in drawable folder and not gon imageView if don't have image(and wrote this in Log  30375:30375 W/EGL_genymotion).

Comment: what does content.getImg() return ?

Comment: have you taken care that the imagename doesn't include extension like .png?

Comment: **"if(content.getImg() == "not")"** : You can't compare strings in Java using `==`. You need to use `if(content.getImg().equals("not"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.show_img);
    if (content.getImg().equalsIgnoreCase( "not")) {
        img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String image = content.getImg();
        int imageResource = c.getResources().getIdentifier(
                "drawable/" + image, null, c.getPackageName());
        img.setImageResource(imageResource);
        Log.i(DBAdapter.TAG, image);
    }
```